# Angular 7 - How to retry an http request on certain response status codes?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, retrywhen

I'm trying to catch http request's errors from an Angular interceptor and handle 401 as logout while retrying a 503 and 504 responses `n` times.

This is my http interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.authenticationService.logout();
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }

        return throwError(error);
      }),
      retryWhen(errors => errors
        .pipe(
          concatMap((error, count) => {
            if (count < 2 && (error.status == 503 || error.status == 504)) {
              return of(error.status);
            }

            return throwError(error);
          }),
          delay(500)
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

I'm 100% sure this code worked when I wrote it because I tested it multiple times but now it's giving me:

```
UnsubscriptionErrorImpl 
{message: "1 errors occurred during unsubscription:↵1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null", name: "UnsubscriptionError", errors: Array(1)}

errors: Array(1)
   0: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null at RetryWhenSubscriber._zoneUnsubscribe (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8506:44) at RetryWhenSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscription.js.Subscription.unsubscribe (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3739:30) at RetryWhenSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.unsubscribe (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3524:38) at RetryWhenSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._unsubscribeAndRecycle (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3541:14) at RetryWhenSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/retryWhen.js.RetryWhenSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:155632:14) at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2717:21) at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3504:18) at InnerSubscriber.rxjs.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8537:29) at Notification.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Notification.js.Notification.observe (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2769:50) at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/delay.js.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:153337:40)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "1 errors occurred during unsubscription:↵1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null"
name: "UnsubscriptionError"
```

Last time it was working, I was using angular 6. Now I'm using angular 7. 
I already tried different rxjs versions to no avail.

How can I fix this and implement a simple retry logic?

EDIT:

I just noticed that if I remove the `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-rxjs';` from the `poliyfills.ts` file then it works but other things stop working.

Comment: I review a similar task in my article: https://medium.com/@alexanderposhtaruk/rx-js-replywhen-use-case-in-iframe-d-angular-spa-d86d35d3bce8

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the stream in case of `401` to avoid further logic.

```js
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.authenticationService.logout();
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
          return EMPTY; // <- add this
        }
```